# MySQL Backup from within MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

This is probably pretty simple, but I can't find the answer in the docs.  Anyway I need to programmatically create a backup of a mysql table.  Typically I would just invoke a "mysqldump" from a batch file or shell script.  In this specific project I cannot access any batch files or outside shell scripts.  I can also not use System.Diagnostrics.Process classes to simulate running mysqldump from the command line.

This leaves me with accomplishing this task from within the MySQL .NET Connector.  How can I mimic "mysqldump" from within a query (in Windows) that I can send to my connection instance then execute?

Thoughts?

Comment: Would [this help](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysqldump+c%23)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a hot backup, I think you are out of luck. All backup options/products require external products to be run. Is this ISAM or INNODB tables?

Comment: They are MyISAM.  If they were INNODB I'd just wrap all my calls in transactions and forget about backups.

Comment: Hmm, I think with MyISAM you can lock the tables, flush them and then copy them to annother table. Of course that brings things to a grinding halt.